# no neutral wire for smart thermostat

Tags: wire, neutral

I want to install a smart thermostat 240 volt but there is no neutral available. Can I connect to the neutral of an adjacent 120 gang box (receptacle)?

Comment: NO............ you cannot steal neutrals from wherever.

Comment: Do you mean 24.0V  for the thermostat?

Comment: @JACK no, this is for electric baseboard heating, so 240V thermostat.  OP are you sure there aren't any neutrals tucked into the back of the box?  Without them you'll need a different thermostat.  The sales clerk should have warned you of this.  On the upside, one tactic for dealing with the "no neutral" problem involves using 24V for controls, and then, you can use **any** smart 'stat including the Nest.  Actually, that might be possible with the wiring in the walls, come to think of it :)

Comment: What make and model is this smart thermostat to begin with?

Comment: Assuming North America, why would a 240V thermostat need neutral?

Comment: @Jasen A 240V thermostat does not need neutral.  A 240V *smart* thermostat may need either neutral or the other pole, to power itself.  (However, a heater is a great use-case for the tradional triac dimmer's method of leaking power through the device, since the resistance of heaters is very low and not likely to be replaced by finicky LED heaters anytime soon :)